# jquery removing empty elements and their empty children

Tags: jquery

So I have dynamic content and want to remove empty elements and empty child elements (if any). There is a few scenarios that occur:

HTML

```
<p> </p>

<p><img src="image.jpg" /></p>

<p><strong></strong></p>
```

jQuery

```
$(".articleContent p").filter( function() {
    return !($.trim($(this).text()).length) && !($(this).children().length);
}).hide()
```

Problem is it doesn't account for empty child elements. I've tried tweaking and it either hides the img or the empty child elements.

Suggestions?

Comment: How can an empty element have any children? Also your first example (`<p> </p>`) isn't quite empty, it has a space in it. Do you mean you want to remove any elements that don't have textual content and/or img elements? (Noting that a parent element may not have text content itself but its children might.) What about `<input>` elements?

Comment: Empty as in no text, whitespace doesn't count (which is why I use trim). An element can have no text and still wrap around an element, therefore it has children. I have noted that a parent can be empty but its child not.

Comment: OK. Your definition of "empty" is different to mine. But anyway, do you mean "no text or img elements"? Your comments under Musa's answer imply that you don't want to hide images, but then one of the examples in the question is `<p><img src="" /></p>`.

Comment: See edit, I forgot to add an image src. By empty I mean no text or any elements, and as I am using trim whitespace is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) method gets the text of the selected element and all its descendants, so you don't need to test children elements for text.

```
$(".articleContent p").filter( function() {
            $this = $(this);
    return (!$.trim($this.text()).length && !$this.has('img').length);
}).hide()
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/yTZh5/1/)

Comment: This still hides the img, seems like it's saying the img has no text therefore hide it.

Comment: @UniAvenger Image tags are empty so I thought you wanted the image hidden, you can just add a condition so that the image is not hidden

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, all the img's are meant to have srcs.

Comment: Oh nice so adding the img condition seems to make it work now. Just need to see if it'll work with other scenarios now. Thanks!

Comment: This works for now but any other elements without text (object, embed etc.) will still be hidden.

Comment: @UniAvenger put all the allowable empty tags in a comma separated string in the `.has()` method. `!$this.has('img,object,embed, etc').length`

Comment: Hah yup that's exactly what I did, it is a good enough solution for now.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the childen() test it seems to work, text() considers the combined text of the selector elements and all desendants.

```
    $(".articleContent p").filter(function () {
        return !($.trim($(this).text()).length);
    }).hide(); // or replace hide() with remove()
```

Comment: Yep. Musa was obviously a few seconds quicker.